# Can't Remote Desktop on LAN, Firewall Rules in Place, Yet Packets Dropped

Tags: active-directory, firewall, group-policy, windows-firewall

I've banged my head for a few hours on this. I'm beginning to move several computers to a new subnet, all Windows 7, all domain joined. On the original subnet (192.168.145.X) everything works as expected. Once put on the VLAN for the new network (10.1.0.X) I can no longer RDP, ping, etc. even between the two on a local switch (e.g. no firewall rules applied).

Turning on logging of dropped packets for the windows firewall shows explicitly that ping and RDP are being dropped by the Windows firewall. I've turned the firewall off, but still cannot connect. I figure that, even as a local administrator, disabling the firewall may still have some GPO firewall settings applied from the domain that it is running, but RDP is enabled via GPO for all connections, all subnets. I've even created local rules on the windows clients to allow RDP.

What drives me up a wall is that if I change the switch to put the computers back on the default VLAN (192.168.145.X) it work with no issues.

If I throw 2 ubuntu VM's on the VLAN (10.1.0.X) I can ping or SSH all day long. I'm thinking it is a Windows Firewall issue, but all the settings seem correct and it works on the original subnet.

What hidden setting am I missing here?

Comment: What's routing the traffic between the two VLAN's? In order to get from 192.168.145.x to 10.1.10.x you need a router.

Comment: pfSense is, but I'm not attempting to connect through a firewall from one subnet to the other. Simply being on the same subnet and attempting to RDP does not work.

Comment: so one machine on 10.1.10.x can't RDP to another machine on 10.1.10.x?

Comment: Correct, and there is an entry in the firewall that says the connection was dropped, despite the firewall allowing any protocol on port 3389. If I turn the firewall off completely, it fails silently

Comment: OK, is the firewall rule configured for the correct network profile? What network profile is currently active and what network location is the network connection using (domain, public, private). The firewall rule profile needs to match the network profile. My guess is that the network profile changed and the firewall rule doesn't match it.

Comment: The rule is configured for all network locations (domain, public, and private) under the domain profile. Since the network connection under the Network and Sharing Center says it is connected to a "Domain Network" when connected to both subnets, I believe that should be using the correct profile.

Comment: On the Scope tab of the rule are the local and remote ip addresses correct?

Comment: Both are set to "Any IP Address"

Comment: Since it hasn't been stated, have you verified that Remote Desktop is enabled while connected to the 10.1.10.0 network? Not sure why it would matter, but just to be sure. Also, is it allowing any connection, or does it require Network Level Authentication?

Comment: Yes it is enabled, and is set to allow any connection